# Initialize cucumber folder structure?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

Is there an easy way to initialize a cucumber folder structure like rails generators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://wiki.github.com/cucumber/cucumber/ruby-on-rails):

```
ruby script/generate cucumber
```

> If you’re on an OS that supports fork (read: !Windows) we recommend you use Spork and —drb as this lets you start cucumber faster:

```
ruby script/generate cucumber --spork
```

> For more help on the generator you can just ask for help:

```
ruby script/generate cucumber --help

ruby script/generate feature Frooble name:string color:string description:text
```

> This will generate a simple plain text feature with associated steps. Don’t get addicted to this generator – you’re better off writing these by hand in the long run.

Comment: But that is for Rails only. Is there a way to do so in an arbitrary folder?

Comment: If you are not using rails, there is not much to generate, cucumber will include all features/support/**/*.rb files where you define your world. You place the features as features/feature_name.feature and steps in features/step_definitions/domain_name.rb

Answer (score 3):

Cucumber has the option to initialize as part of execution

```
cucumber --init
```